# get data from mailchip using curl where do I place the api key in the curl call

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am tryng to get list members from a mailchimp using curl.

This is my code.

I cant figure where to place the api key.

this is the code I have for now:

```
$apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$list_id = 'aaaaaaaaaa';
$dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);

$url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list_id;

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

curl_close($cURL);

echo '<pre>';

var_dump($result);

echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have read [mailchimp documents](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/), maybe you need to add `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option.

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $apiKey);
```

please set your username of mailchimp to `$username`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the code but still no success...
What can be the problem?